# Overriding configuration folder defaults

Tags: init-file, gnus, config

I have a few different configuration files for Gnus. I don't fully understand best practice here, but I'd like to move them out of my user home directory so that my path is `~/.emacs.d/gnus/gnus`, `~/.emacs.d/gnus/profile`, etc... how do I configure this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, gnus config is placed in `~/.gnus`. You can change this to another value via customize: `M-x customize-variable gnus-init-file`. Perhaps you'd like to set this to `~/.emacsd/gnus/gnus`?

You can load other files from the `gnus` file, so if you put `profile` in `~/.emacs.d/gnus/profile`, you could add this to `gnus`:

```
(add-to-path 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/gnus")
(load "profile")
```

You could also put that in your init.el file.